# Node.js http request pipelining

Tags: http, node.js, pipelining

So, I want to use node.js and http request pipelining, but I want to use HTTP only as a transport, nothing else. I am interested in exploiting the request pipelining feature. However, one problem that I am running into is that till a send a response to a previous request, the next requests's callback isn't fired by node. I want a way to be able to do this. I shall be handling the ordering of results in the application. Is there a way to do this?

The HTTP RFC mentions that the responses should be in order, but I don't see any reason for node.js to not call the next callback till the 1st one is responded to. The application can in theory send the response to the 2nd query as a response to the 1st one (as long as there is some way for the recipient to know that it is a response to the 2nd one).

Comment: Okay, there doesn't seem to be any way that I can see. Will have to write an HTTP parser and server component.

Comment: Did you ask on the Node.js IRC channel? (on freenode) Theres plenty of very good help there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTTP client in `NodeJS` [does not support pipelining](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/msg/b36c4279e8e053f4).  (Slightly old post from Ryan, but I'm fairly sure it still holds.)

Comment: Well, if the client does not support pipelining, there are very slim chances of it supporting what I wanted!! Thanks!! :-)