# pipeline implementation in node.js

Tags: node.js

How can we implement pipeline feature for the http requests in node.js ?

I want to process a list of requests and in which i need to implement pipeline.

can any one explain how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Node.js http request pipelining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127629/node-js-http-request-pipelining), node.js http client does not support this.

There is also not a node.js SPDY client.