# Node.js pipelining HTTP client agent?

Tags: node.js, http, rfc2616, http-pipelining

The HTTP client built into Node.js [doesn't seem to support pipelining requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776649/362536).  However, it occurred to me that it may be possible to create an [Agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) that sets up pipelining in the background.  There may be issues getting the response data back the way it should be, but perhaps the Agent could fake out some socket objects to make the HTTP client work like normal?

Has this been done?  Alternatively, is there an alternative HTTP client that is a drop-in replacement for the main that supports pipelining?  (Ultimately, I'd like to use it with the AWS SDK, so it needs to be compatible.)